# C circular dependency with headers

Tags: c

I am working on a project where I have to follow guidelines on the organization of the files and I can't get it to compile.

To simplify it I have a main.h where I HAVE to define bool and some symbols to go along with it:

```
#ifndef main_h
#define main_h

#include <stdio.h>
#include "test.h"

typedef unsigned char    bool;
#define TRUE  1
#define FALSE 0

#endif /* main_h */
```

Then the main.c HAS to use a type "num_seconds_t" and a function "test()", both of which have to be in a seperate file from main.

so I have my test.h:

```
#ifndef test_h
#define test_h

#include <stdio.h>
#include "main.h"

typedef int32_t num_seconds_t;
bool test(num_seconds_t var);

#endif /* test_h */
```

and my test.c:

```
#include "test.h"

bool test(num_seconds_t var){
    num_seconds_t test = var;
    return TRUE;
}
```

I don't think main.c would have any affect on this issue.

The error states unknown type "bool" in my test.h file, and I kind of understand why as when it hits the include for "test.h" within the main.h it starts going through that file before it has defined bool in main.h, then since main.h has "#ifndef main_h" when it hits "#include "main.h"" in the test.h it skips this and continues reading so bool never gets defined until after the test.h is done being read.

I am not sure if my understanding is correct, but what is the proper way of solving this. By simply moving the "#include "test.h"" to after the definition of bool it will compile, but in my big project I have many files that intertwine and coordinating the order of including these files would be very tough if not impossible.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have `#include "test.h"` in your main header? It seems unnecessary there

Comment: move your typedefs into a third file and include that in both test and main.

Comment: @UnholySheep because I use a the test() from test.c function in main.c

Comment: @SamyBencherif the requirements of the project state that typedef bool must be in main.h and typedef num_seconds_t must be in test.h

Comment: Also if `A.h` includes `B.h` and `B.h` includes `A.h` it seems that the two files should be merged into a single one from the logical point of view. If you really want to keep `main.h` and `test.h` separated, indeed the only option is a third file included in both headers as commented above.

Comment: In that case you should be including test.h inside the main.c file, not the header - including headers only where you actually need them solves a lot of headaches

Comment: @VladRusu its part of the project and I am not allowed to define the types anywhere else. I agree it would be more logical to do it that way though

Comment: @UnholySheep I think including it in the main.c might be the only solution

Comment: You could also just move the `#include "test.h"` below the the bool typedef in main.h.  But in general headers shouldn't include other headers unless 1) they have to, or 2) their entire *purpose* is to include other headers to effectively create a full API for a C file to access.

Comment: Aside: Why create `typedef unsigned char    bool;` instead of using C boolean type  `_Bool` or `bool via #include `<stdboolh.h>`?

Answer (score 2):

I'll present 3 solutions:

1) Your best option is to not `#include` `test.h` in `main.h`, since you don't need anything defined in `test.h` in `main.h` (you do need stuff from `test.h` in `main.c`, so `test.h` should be `#include`ed in `main.c`). This is good practice in general, as described in the comments (you don't want to `#include` something you don't need).

2) Your second best option is to move things from `test.h` and `main.h` to another file. In this case, you'd want to move your `typedef`s and `#define`s to another file like so:

```
typedef unsigned char bool;
#define TRUE  1
#define FALSE 0
typedef int32_t num_seconds_t;
```

and then include this file in `main.h` and `test.h` (or just in `test.h` because `main.h doesn't need these typedefs).

3) Your last and worst option is to carefully choose the order in which you include things. This is your worst option, since it gets very unwieldy with a large project, but I will show it nonetheless.

Leaving all your other files the same and doing:

```
// main.c

#include test.h
```

as the only include in `main.c` will solve your problem. When you try to compile this, only `test.h` will be `#include`ed in `main.c`. This will then include `main.h`, which has the typedefs you need for `test.h`. `main.h` won't include `test.h` again, since it has already been included. This is okay, because `main.h` doesn't actually need `test.h`.

You could also move your `#include` in `main.h` below your typedefs and include `main.h` in `main.c`. As I mentioned, however, option 3 is not a good option.

You should really do some combination of options 1 and 2 (in general, not just for this project).

Comment: I would think that option 2 in your list is the best option for this posted question. It means having fewer include files to manage.

Comment: @RichardChambers I think in general having all your typedefs in one place really helps with structure for larger projects (and not having this is much harder to fix than having too many includes). For this question I think you're right though, will edit.

Comment: although it's worth noting that the OP's requirements basically make the best option (#2 imo) impossible.

Comment: @zzxyz yes, I think pulling them out to a separate file is in general the right solution, but with OPs restrictions it's not possible. So not including extra things is the best option for OP IMHO.

Comment: @zzxyz I must be missing something as I am not seeing what I think is now option 1 (the option formerly known as 2)  with the modified answer makes using it impossible. I don't see a dependency of main.h on test.h and I would suggest that doing an include of test.h on main.h doesn't make sense. I would recommend that any include directives in an include file should be pertinent to the include file itself and would be only those directives, declarations, and definitions that are required by the include file.

Comment: @RichardChambers Read the OPs post paying particular attention to his all caps phrases. His requirements are absurd (through no fault of his own I’m sure). The comments in the ? clarify as well.

Comment: @zzxyz I see no all caps phrases, just two all caps words in two different paragraphs for two different include files, `main.h` and `test.h`, which appear to have extraneous material other than what it appears he "requires", e.g. the `include` directives. I see no requirement for the `include <stdio.h>` in either of the include files nor the `include "test.h" in `main.h`. I've said I don't see it. I'm not interested in guessing games.

Comment: @RichardChambers - I'm not interested in spelling out what the OP has already spelled out, as long as we're being rude.;